# How can I get the column name of the primary key of a Database Table from the ResultSet or ResultSetMetaData object in JAVA?

Tags: java, jdbc, metadata, resultset

I am writing a Java Application. I have got a ResultSet. Now I want to find out the coloumn name of the primary key of the table.

Is it possible to get that coloumn name through ResultSet object or ResultSetMetaData Object or any other way.

I didn't find any way to find this.

Comment: What's wrong with looking at the database to see how the table was defined?  When there are multiple unique key constraints, one could be "primary" as far as users are concerned and a surrogate key is defined as primary in the database.  Why do you want to try and automate this?

Answer (score 9):

No. You will not get that information from **ResultSet** or **ResultSetMetadata**.

What you want to use for that is [**DatabaseMetadata**](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) class. From that class check **getPrimaryKeys** method to get the information you want.

Of course, to use this, you will need to know the name of the table.

Comment: What does "catalog" and "schema" means? Is "schema" referring to the database name?

Comment: @Yatendra, what DB are you using?  Those are common in DB2.  If you use eclipse, and connect with the "Database Development" view, you'll be able to figure it out on your own.

Comment: @ericp, I am using Eclipse IDE and MySQL database. But I don't want my code to be dependent on any particular database.

Comment: A quick google search, found http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/Database-Metadata-with-JDBC/13753 - :Sometimes, for a given problem, there are different solutions based on the database vendor. For example, the code that gets the table names for an Oracle database is different from the code that gets the tables names for a MySQL database. When you develop an application or framework for a relational database, be sure that your connection pool manager takes the vendor name as a parameter."

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz : thanks! I am looking for this answer. Why it's not accepted anyway?

Answer (score 3):

I want to add, if in a table you have autoincrement field, it must be the primary key. So, your code could look like this:

```
if(metaColumn.isAutoIncrement(i)) {
  primaryKey = metaColumn.getColumnName(i);
  i=nColoumn+1;
}
```

It uses `ResultSetMetaData`.

Comment: This would fail if the primary key is not an identity.

Comment: Maybe my experience is limited to MySQL, but in MySQL, an autoincrement must be a primary key. Cmiiw.

Answer (score 0):

A nice tool which you can use to verify the metadata information is [dbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/).

It uses the JDBC metadata to retrieve table definitions and other parts of the database. Schema and Catalog are columns in the table definition view - so you can check which values are in these columns for your favorite database.

dbVisualizer is available in a free basic version.